# Trying to make cold warm hot using C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make cold hot warm game using C++ using loops and for statement but for some reason after If statement the loop stops and does not continue. Can someone tell me how can i fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int rand1, input;
    srand(time(NULL));
    rand1 = rand() % (100 - 1) + 1;
    cout << "Try guessing the number between 1 - 100" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        cin >> input;
        if (input > rand1) {
            cout << "Hot" << endl;
        }
        else if (input < rand1) {
            cout << "Cold" << endl;
        }
    }

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Best thing to do is to go through it line by line with a debugger and see what isn't the way you think it is.

Comment: Please post the relevant code (narrowed down to a minimal, representative example) directly in your question.

Comment: If you debug it and find what the problem is and explain it then maybe we can tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @KerrekSB Just did that for OP

Comment: i tried using debugger to find the error but it goes to "ostream" file every time

Comment: @LukaRusadzeLukaRuso Check my answer below.

Comment: Write a piece of code that runs the CPU and graphics adapter at full power. That will get you hot. To get cold, simply turn off the PC. For warm, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your if-statement; Your for-loop is missing a `break` statement that terminates the loop and exits the game if the user guesses the right number.

Without the `break` statement, the loop to continue running even after you have guessed the right number, as the loop is conditioned to run from `i = 1` to `i = 100`.

Add a break statement like:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    cin >> input;
    if (input > rand1) {
        cout << "Hot" << endl;
    }
    else if (input < rand1) {
        cout << "Cold" << endl;
    }
    else { //       <---- If the user enters the correct number:
        cout << "Success! The correct number WAS" << rand1 << endl;  // Output success statement
        break; //   <---- Break out of the for-loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the first two lines of the question? I couldn't figure out what the op wanted from there. :(

Comment: @sjsam Neither could I, but when I ran the code, I figured that there was no check if the user entered the right number.

Comment: @sjsam Some questions are so easy, they don't even need any explaination ;)

Comment: A logical assumption and willingness to help is much appreciated but that doesn't mean that the question is answered. ;) In fact only the op knows the question which I think they didn't reproduce properly.

Comment: @sjsam True... The warm part still has me stumped. I didn't see any reference to "_warm_" in the code. But, a bit of help goes a long way, that's the way I see it :)